# How to add on checked and subract on unchecked using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can you add 25 when you check that box and subtract 25 when you uncheck it on the number that is inside the span id="preciototal" ?

Take a look here please.
Its part of a checkout form and the idea is it calculates the total price:

http://jsfiddle.net/9YGBu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative answer which demonstrates a few more advanced jQuery concepts to you, consider the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // cache anything reused in variables
    var $zonaenvio = $("#zonaenvio");
    var $gelypilas = $('#gelypilas');
    var $totalprecio = $('#totalprecio');
    var $totalSpan = $('#preciototal');
    // declare a function that does everything
    var updatePrice = function() {
        // get the value of the selected product, or 0 if nothing selected
        var productAmount = parseInt($zonaenvio.val() || '0');
        if (productAmount > 0) {
            // if something selected, calculate correct total and show it
            var correctTotal = productAmount + ($gelypilas.is(':checked') ? 25 : 0);
            $totalSpan.text(correctTotal);
            $totalprecio.show('slow');
        } else {
            // otherwise, if nothing selected, hide the total information
            $totalprecio.hide();
        }
    };
    // bind the function to the input events
    $zonaenvio.change(updatePrice).change(); // trigger once if needed
    $gelypilas.change(updatePrice);

});
```

Does that make sense? See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/X4VtE/3/) for a working jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking for something like this!

http://jsfiddle.net/9YGBu/21/

**Mind that I have added an id to the checkbox, you may wanna change the selector to work with the name property instead**

Comment: its great! but one more sub-question. How would u also add the final value to an input's value?

Lets say the TOTAL is 400 i need to put 400 in an input's value="here" becuase thats the price that gets posted to a checkout service

Comment: @RenatoGama answer is not completely correct, if the checkbox is already checked and the user selects a different option from the dropdown and then the user unchecks the radio box, it will display an incorrect value. My answer takes care of unchecking the radio when the user changes the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, I cached the selector for optimization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var precioTotal = $("#preciototal"), gelypilas = $('#gelypilas'),
        totalPrecio = $('#totalprecio'), zonaEnvio = $("#zonaenvio");
zonaEnvio.change(function() {
     precioTotal.text($(this).val());
     gelypilas.removeAttr('checked');
     totalPrecio.show("slow");
}).change(); // trigger once if needed
    gelypilas.change(function(){
        if(gelypilas.attr('checked')){
            precioTotal.text(parseInt(precioTotal.text()) + 25);
        }else{
            precioTotal.text(Math.max(0, parseInt(precioTotal.text()) - 25));
        }
    });
});
```